# Google App Engine with Cloud Storage not Working Locally

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am running a Wordpress site on Google Appengine. It is using the GAE plugin for wordpress. The media library works on appengine server but not locally. Same for most of the images unless they have hardcoded links. I get tons of 404 errors...

`http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/<BUCKET_NAME>/image.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

where as this link on gae server works:

`http://<BUCKET_NAME>.storage.googleapis.com/image.png`

I am running my app locally like this:
`dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/php-cgi .`

It seems google's python script is not correctly forwarding the link to the actual real bucket.... any ideas?

Comment: Those files are copied over to your local server? I would have assumed the dev side could just access those asset right off the web, rather than local copies. 

This question/answers might help you some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597338/how-do-i-enable-google-cloud-storage-on-my-local-development-server

Comment: Have you set a `--storage_path=` flag path for your local env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour:

The link `http://<BUCKET_NAME>.storage.googleapis.com/image.png` is the production link, and the request is served from the production server.

The link `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/<BUCKET_NAME>/image.png` is a local link, and the devserver has to actually contain `<BUCKET_NAME>/image.png`. It's likely that the object is only stored in production, leading to a 404 when attempting to find it on the local machine.

As a solution, you might consider simply running your local tests against the production cloud storage, to save the cost of transferring (and maintaining the sync of) all the storage items to local, which will almost certainly cost more in network transfer and dev-time than this simpler alternative.

Comment: I see, thx for the explanation. Makes sense. The weird thing is that I that i use an exact copy of our prod db in local env. I assume these links are handled by the appengine wp plugin. Do you know where that url transformation is made?

Comment: Ah, I see, this is in the context of wordpress. I had missed that. My best advice is to run grep on the wordpress codebase and see if _ah/gcs appears anywhere: `grep -R _ah/gcs <wordpress directory>`. I'd also take a look at the locations in the PHP SDK which deal with such URLs. For example, `CloudStorageTools.php` has a class method `CloudStorageTools.getPublicUrl()` which contains this code: `if (self::isDevelServer()) {      ...    $path = sprintf('%s/%s%s', self::LOCAL_ENDPOINT, $bucket, $object);     ... `

Comment: ^^^ that code seems to assume that you'll be either syncing your local GCS or populating it fresh for each test run, which isn't the case. I see nothing wrong with monkey-patching that conditional branch out of the picture and forcing it to use production URLs every time, but you might want to also raise all this information in a [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) Feature Request, and we can see what's the best path forward, maybe a command-line flag when starting the devserver, something like `--gcs-use-production-urls-only=True`

Comment: So i rsynced the cloud storage to my local drive and tried to specifiy the local folder then with `--storage_path=./bucket` which does not work. do you have any links to documentation... i could not find any yet?!

Comment: How do you "run it against the production cloud storage" system without fully deploying the app?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the same exact issue, but I found that all of my gcs requests from dev_appserver.py were getting routed to

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/<BUCKET_NAME>/<OBJECT_NAME>
```

... as opposed to the "real" gcs url, e.g.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<BUCKET_NAME>/<OBJECT_NAME>
```

...therefore resulting in 404 errors when making GET requests for gcs objects.

## TLDR

I was able to remedy this issue by simply setting an access token, e.g.

```python
cloudstorage.common.set_access_token("<TOKEN>")
```

*See the `set_access_token` docstring below for how to acquire an access token.

Once that I did that, all of my gcs requests were properly routed.

## Details

After digging through the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client) of `appengine-gcs-client`, it looks like you must first set an access token if you would like to use dev_appserver to access live/remote content in gcs.

In [cloudstorage.common](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/655e4eb92da93236b9050a7b3f47509d2258ead6/python/src/cloudstorage/common.py#L74-L88):

```py
def set_access_token(access_token):
  """Set the shared access token to authenticate with Google Cloud Storage.
  When set, the library will always attempt to communicate with the
  real Google Cloud Storage with this token even when running on dev appserver.
  Note the token could expire so it's up to you to renew it.
  When absent, the library will automatically request and refresh a token
  on appserver, or when on dev appserver, talk to a Google Cloud Storage
  stub.
  Args:
    access_token: you can get one by run 'gsutil -d ls' and copy the
      str after 'Bearer'.
  """
```

Some additional hints/options in [cloudstorage.storage_api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/655e4eb92da93236b9050a7b3f47509d2258ead6/python/src/cloudstorage/storage_api.py#L44-L60):

```py
def _get_storage_api(retry_params, account_id=None):
  """Returns storage_api instance for API methods.
  Args:
    retry_params: An instance of api_utils.RetryParams. If none,
     thread's default will be used.
    account_id: Internal-use only.
  Returns:
    A storage_api instance to handle urlfetch work to GCS.
    On dev appserver, this instance will talk to a local stub by default.
    However, if you pass the arguments --appidentity_email_address and
    --appidentity_private_key_path to dev_appserver.py it will attempt to use
    the real GCS with these credentials.  Alternatively, you can set a specific
    access token with common.set_access_token.  You can also pass
    --default_gcs_bucket_name to set the default bucket.
  """
```

## Misc Info

### pip libs

```
google-api-python-client==1.6.4
GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient==1.9.22.1
```

### gcloud libs

```
Google Cloud SDK 200.0.0
alpha 2018.04.30
app-engine-python 1.9.69
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.69
beta 2018.04.30
bq 2.0.33
cloud-datastore-emulator 1.4.1
core 2018.04.30
gsutil 4.31
```