# issues serving images with get_serving_url() on local dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud-storage

I have uploaded some sample images to the GCS bucket and trying to generate the URL based on the image as follows:

```
    filename = "/gs/ABC/abc.jpeg"
    blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key(filename)
    serving_url = images.get_serving_url(blobkey, secure_url=True)
```

The serving_url i get is something like this
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:dGVzdGltYWdlczEvaWc=

But whenever I access the url in browser, I get the following message in the console log:

Could not find blob with key encoded_gs_file:dGVzdGltYWdlczEvaWc=s200

Any idea why this isn't working? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the appengine localhost uses a fake GCS mounted out of local temp folder (hence the prefix `encoded_gs_file:`).

You can get the `cloudstorage` lib to access your actual buckets, by specifying the bucket names, and doing

```
cloudstorage.common.set_access_token(gcs_token)
```

where `gcs_token` equals the output of

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838216/4458510

However I'm not sure if `blobstore.create_gs_key()` & `images.get_serving_url()` can be coerced to use non-local paths.

I actually have an init script to prime my localhost with data from production, perhaps you'll want to make one too that downloads these files and injects them into your local environment.